# Show all running tasks in Assembly

Tags: cpu, process, threads, assembly

Is it possible to show/log everything what the CPU does? The CPU knows what it executes, so it could print the running threads/tasks on the screen or in a file.

Comment: If you _could_ do that (you can't), your computer would crawl to a snail's pace (at best) waiting for disks and/or screen updates.

Comment: No; Its not possible. Most applications are not written in Assembly, even if they were, even assembly programs are compiled into an executable. Once that happens that human language ( assembly ) is lost and translated directly to machine code.

Comment: But isn't every assembly line a direct Translation of machine code. If you know the machine code of an executable, then you should be able to translate it backwards to assembly. Isn't that how disassembly works?